# How to make Laravel Password hash using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bcrypt

I have a laravel website which transfer all its data to Hybird mobile app using html css and js. Mobile app works in offline mode. I have to perform authentication in mobile which is based on data transfered from website. But laravel uses bcrypt hash. How can i make similar hasher to match password in javascript?? Is it possible to make similar hasher in javascript or somebody have done this already??

Comment: I think we need more information, so laravel is php (php tag is missing in your post), so what is your "mobile app" ? for which platform? And then you mention a website. what website? the website where you use laravel/php to output data to be received by your mobile app?

Comment: May i see the code that you have so far ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to answer your vague question (assuming you are looking for a bcrypt library for javascript):

1) there  is one bcrypt library for javascript here:
https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt
found here:
[bCrypt implementation in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299434/bcrypt-implementation-in-javascript)

I would assume (but am not sure) that laravel uses the php built-ins `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`, thus outputting a special format which containts the used salt like this example from php doc:

`$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';`

You can look at the php documentation for both:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

You would need to adapt the hash-string so that you can use it inside the javascript bcrypt function to verify a user-provided password in your mobile app.

**Update**

The salt is stored inside the hash, so you can extract it for your javascript verification - just take the first 22 characters *after* the prefix "$2y$10$" (salt is "saltsaltsaltsaltsaltse" in this example):

```
echo password_hash('JohnDoe', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt' => 'saltsaltsaltsaltsaltse']);
# will output $2y$10$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltseQMyqgPkFxQ1hfP2yBcGxgbJZGe1uGXq
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to hassans research, the javascript library is found to be compatible with hashes from `phps` `password_hash()` *without* splitting the hash and/or prividing the salt separately.
To avoid the **"Invalid salt revision"** error for php-generated hashes within the js lib, one has to replace `$2y` with `$2a` in the hash prefix. Hashes from the js lib can be used by php without replacing.

Comment: thanks for your responce. i tried this javascript library. In this library there is some example scripts. One is to varify password against hash. So if i try to varify password against the hash from my database it gives me "invalid salt revision" alert. I dont think i have set any salt in my laravel application. Do you have any idea??

Comment: You can show your appreciation by upvoting my answer at first. And then, i cannot answer your comment, because I dont know how laravel saves its hashes or if it uses afore-mentioned php functions. You have to give more input, for example, show us one complete of your hashes.

Comment: I dont think that you have read the php functions I mentioned. If you did, you can see that salts are generated automatically by those functions!

Comment: Sorry dear, i upvoted it and yes its helping me in right direction. Yes laravel using both the above standard php functions to generate hash. A hash generated by this js library is able to match by php function. But when php generated hash is matched against password using this library it throws "invalid salt revision" exception. To show you a complete laravel generate brcypt hash here is one $2y$10$YSwUd0uHBE9hvK9i49r48eGnAMkuSMJaMOGgzcyLCfOewZoK59ZDW against password "admin123".

Comment: And when you try to verify this hash inside javascript, what salt are you using? the salt should be the first 22 characters after the prefix "$2y$10$". I actually just tried that, and because I had a question myself about how to retrieve the correct salt I opened a new thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673318/how-to-retrieve-the-correct-salt-from-phps-password-hash

Comment: No i am not providing any salt. When varifyin i just give password string and password hash. If hash is generated by this js library it works but not in php case.

Comment: But the passwords do use a salt, so you have to, too. You must provide the javascript function the salt from the password. Please see above how to retrieve the salt. Should be the first 22 characters.

Comment: Ok i you have downloaded and used this js library, the method that matches the hash against password does not take salt to match. Anyways i searched for the exception "invalid salt revision" and found this answer https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/issues/49 . Now hashes generated by PHP are able to match using this js library by replacing $2y to $2a and hashes generated from this js library are able to be recognized by php by replacing $2a to $2y. So i am marking your answer as correct. You can modify your answer to include this so that any one can solve it without reading comments.

Comment: I am unable to edit my comment so adding another one. Hashes generated by js library can be be varified without replacing @2a to $2y. Php recognize them both ways. Thanks for your help dear.

Answer (score 1):

I think all authentication should be done on the backend server(in this case using laravel). You should not transfer your users information to the client mobile app for offline authentication. There are several problems that may arise, confidential data can be exposed, most recently registered user information may not be present on the offline mobile app, etc.

Now I will suggest you to authenticate/register the user by being online and then do the other operation in offline mode. Check the authentication periodically after 6 or 7 days.

But if you still need that every bcrypt algorithm should result in the same hash, so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299434/bcrypt-implementation-in-javascript) is a discussion that should help.

**NOTE**: `Authentication should not be done on client side.`

Comment: Actually application will sync data periodically to get updated data. More ever application is not a public application, but will be used by specific people only. And it must work offline because where this application will be used, at that place there is no assurity of internet access availability everytime. So this is a requirement to authenticate the current user in offline mode.

Comment: I think in this case, the mobile app is not a 2-tier client-server architecture, but should be an offline usable independent app. so it should offer encryption or protection for the data, thus one needs to authenticate to open the data. This seems totally ok to me.

Comment: Ok, instead of **authentication**; **encryption** should be used in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is to make an API call to bucrypt.

### First call ajax  from your app with the request data

eg(using jQuery):

```
var stringToHash = 'mypassword'; 
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data:{password:stringToHash },
   success: function(response){
      console.log('here you get response');
     /*now the hash code*/
      console.log(response.data);

   }
});
```

### In Laravel api Controller(laravel 5)

```
public function hashPassword()
 {
      $hashPassword =  bcrypt(Input::get('password'));

      return response()->json([
                        'status' => 'success', 
                        'data' => $hashPassword
                        ]);

 }
```

Comment: You didn't get the question completely. Read the question again and the above answers as well.