# How to retrieve the correct salt from phps password_hash()?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt, php-password-hash

I know that the salt is included in the output of `phps` `password_hash()`, but when I execute the following:

```
echo password_hash('JohnDoe', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt' => 'saltsaltsaltsaltsaltsh']);
# this will be $2y$10$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltseQMyqgPkFxQ1hfP2yBcGxgbJZGe1uGXq
```

I can see only part of the original salt, the last character seems to be truncated or somehow converted to something else?
So, how do I get the last character of the salt?

**Update**
Sorry, let me clarify my question: How can I get the salt out of the returned hash from phps password_hash() function? I do not plan on using custom-salts, just want to get the php-provided one. My example is just to show, that my 22-len string is not fully represented in the hash, there only 21 charachters of my salt are visible. Why? Where is the last charachter?

Comment: Offtopic but the salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: And also `*Caution*
It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.`

Comment: You can't get the last character of the original salt when it's longer than required, but you can get as many characters as you actually need..... the salt is truncated and then used, and the stored salt is all that's needed to handle the verify

Comment: Salt length is hard-coded to pad/truncate to `$required_salt_len = 22;`

Comment: Yes I know that one should **not** use a custom salt, my question is _"How can I get the php-created salt out of the hash_"

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for your contribution, but please - verify what you are saying. My provied hash _IS_ 22 chars long, and all of those chars are _somehow_ used, _BUT_ I can see only 21 of the original 22 chars in the hash returned back! So for clarification I updated my question above.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727257/length-of-salt-in-crypt-blowfish should answer your question: only 4 bits of the 22nd byte are actually used for a Blowfish salt

Comment: Yes - ok that is the answer, thanks. I would mark is my answer, but you just commented, so I cant.