# Generate password by button in blade file

Tags: laravel, hash, laravel-blade

inside `Laravel Blade file` I'm trying to achieve a simple password generator button that inputs generated password in field

Button:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onClick=generatePass()>Generate Me</a>


<script>
    function generatePass() {
        var hashed_random_password = Hash::make(str_random(12));
            $('#password').val(hashed_random_password);
        }
                
</script>
```

The button works, tested by using `console.log('button clicked');`
But hashing doesn't work, I need to achieve generating a hashed password and inputs it value directly into the `password form field`

Any suggestion how to get that simply in `blade` without invloving the `routes` and `controller` files?

Comment: It appears you are mixing up PHP code (`Hash::make`) with javascript code. I'd recommend that you choose the javascript route only to achieve your goal.

Comment: `var hashed_random_password = "{{ Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make(str_random(12)) }}"`

Comment: @sta this only works the first time, can't use it next time

Comment: @Mysteryos And will you suggest please the  javascript route??

Comment: @JessicaKimble I think you can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670341/how-to-make-laravel-password-hash-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onClick=generatePass()>Generate Me</a>

<script>
  function generatePass() {
    var pass = '';
    var str='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    +  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$';

   for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) { 
      var char = Math.floor(Math.random()* str.length + 1); 
            pass += str.charAt(char) 
        } 
  $('#password').val(pass);
    }
```

Now at your laravel controller Hash this password.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Hash::make` in javascript, that is a PHP/Laravel method.

You can use something like this to generate a random hash:

```js
function generatePass() {
    // change 12 to the length you want the hash
    let randomPasswordHash = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(12);

    $('#password').val(randomPasswordHash);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

blade:

```
<button onclick="generateRandomPassword()">Generate Password</button>
<h2 id="password"></h2>

<script>
    function generateRandomPassword() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/generate-password',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#password').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

route/controller:

```
Route::any('/generate-password', function () {
    return Hash::make(Str::random(12)); 
});
```